# Inject javascript entry point into html files with webpack dev server?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Is it possible to inject the JS entry point into the webpack dev server, much like the CSS is injected inline?

For example, my index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But what I would like to see is, after running my webpack dev server, something like this (note that the CSS is injected automatically, although I do not see the js reference):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>app</title>
    <style>*,*:after,*:before{margin:0;padding:0}html{ /* .. all other styles */ }</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js?1d8f26165af69413a6bb"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, its possible. You need to use [HTML Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin)

The plugin will generate an HTML5 file for you that includes all your webpack bundles in the body using script tags. Just add the plugin to your webpack config as follows:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var webpackConfig = {
  entry: 'index.js',
  output: {
    path: 'dist',
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()]
};
```

This will generate a file dist/index.html containing the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Webpack App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="index_bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I needed. I ended up using a template, as I needed the `<div id="app"></div>` inside. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work for dev server for some reason